# Не получается установить Django

Tags: python, django, cmd, pip

При попытке установить Django возникает такая проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновить pip тоже не получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь установить Django и pip в системную папку, значит нужно запускать pip в командной строке с правами администратора

Comment: @andreymal, пробовал, всё равно отказано в доступе

Comment: Проверьте, существует файл `c:\python39\scripts\django-admin.py`?

Comment: @insolor, нет такого файла

Comment: Установку django запускаете от того же пользователя, от которого устанавливали Python?

Comment: @insolor, пробовал и от него и от админа

Comment: Удалите Python. Установите заново, потом от этого же пользователя пробуйте устанавливать django.